# How to see Answer Accepted percentage?

Tags: feature-request

How can a user see **Accepted Answers percentage**
By Accepted answers percentage I do not refer to the percentage of answers to his/her questions the user accepted but I refer to the precentage of the Users answers that were accepted by other question posters.

I know the former gets displayed on the user's profile, How about the latter, Where can it be seen or If there is no way to see it at present, Can we have a feature to display it, because it would definitly indicate the repute of an user.

Comment: What's with the anonymous downvoting?

Comment: people don't agree with your feature request [MetaSO voting differences](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @Sathya: does this downvoting rule apply also for downvoting answers?

Comment: @TomasTelensky Yes, it does

Comment: @Als: *All* downvoting is anonymous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [a similar query in the data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/100/users-with-highest-accept-rate-of-their-answers), and modified it to show this. [Here it is for your account](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1717/user-answer-accepted-rate?UserId=452307).

The data in the data explorer is only updated periodically, so this isn't up-to-date.

Comment: I entered my userid in it...My results are wrong :(

Comment: @xs2bush: Oops, I forgot to mention that the data explorer doesn't use the live data from the site. Editing the post.

Answer (score 4):

> "It would definitely indicate the repute of an user."

No, *at best* it would indicate a combination of:

- How good the user's answers were.
- How much traffic those questions got and how many competing answers.
- What kind of users the answerer typically helped.
- Personal factors:  Is the answerer collecting grudges?

Anyway, here is [my query in Data explorer for this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1718/answer-success-rate).

[Your results](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1718/answer-success-rate?UserId=452307):

```
                 Count Percent
---------------- ----- -------
Total Answers     528   100.0
Others Accepted   126    23.9
Self Answered       3     0.6
```

**Keep in mind that the Data Explorer lags the main sites by about a month.**

Comment: I entered my id in your query but gives wrong results :(

Comment: Yup Jeremy just told me...Ill wait a little more...thanks

Comment: @xs2bush:  I see from [your SO profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/428110/xs2bush?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_graph), that you got almost all your rep after July 20th.  So it's not yet in the DE, sorry!  You can put in a feature request for more frequent updates, maybe.

Comment: I was just checking coz the link was there....I actually dont care that much about my acceptance rate...should I???

Comment: I do care about my rep but like i said in my answer acceptance rate alone is not a true measure of who is giving good answers...the asking user may not find your answer useful in his/her particular scenario but others do thats where upvotes come in..dont u think???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not displayed so that the user's decision is not biased.  Acceptance is already adding to one's reputation, which shows the degree of trust the community has in a person, which is measured by accepted answers + upvotes.

The acceptance rate alone can't do proper justice in all cases.